# Using Omnipay in OctoberCMS plugin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, omnipay, octobercms

I'm working on a plugin for [OctoberCMS](http://www.octobercms.com) and will use Omnipay. I've done a research and found some packages that integrates the Omnipay library with Laravel as [ignited/omnipay](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay) and [barryvdh/laravel-omnipay](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-omnipay). I've tried both of them by following this steps (all on the plugin directory):

- Create a `composer.json` file and add this:

  ```
  {
      "name": "BalanceRecharge Plugin",
      "email": "webmaster@root.com",
      "require": {
          #in this case I'm using barryvdh/laravel-omnipay
          "barryvdh/laravel-omnipay": "0.1.*", 
          "omnipay/omnipay": "*"
      }
  }
  ```
- Run `composer update` for update library and dependencies, all good
- Add `'Barryvdh\Omnipay\ServiceProvider'` to the providers:

  ```
  'providers' => array_merge(include(base_path().'/modules/system/providers.php'), array(

      // 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider', // Example

      'System\ServiceProvider',
      'Barryvdh\Omnipay\ServiceProvider',
  )),
  ```
- Then try to run the command `php artisan config:publish barryvdh/laravel-omnipay` but get the error below:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Barryvdh\Omnipay\ServiceProvider' not found
>   in
>   /var/www/html/alomicuba/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php
>   on line 157 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   /var/www/html/alomicuba/artisan:0 PHP   2. require_once()
>   /var/www/html/alomicuba/artisan:30 PHP   3. require()
>   /var/www/html/alomicuba/bootstrap/start.php:57 PHP   4.
>   Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load()
>   /var/www/html/alomicuba/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php:210
>   PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->compileManifest()
>   /var/www/html/alomicuba/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:57
>   PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->createProvider()
>   /var/www/html/alomicuba/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:121

What I'm doing wrong? What is the right way to register the Provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use laravel packages in plugin you have to register service provider and alias in plugin.php

**Register the plugins Service Provider**
In your Plugin.php's boot() method, add

`\App::register('\Third\Party\ServiceProvider');`.

This is how you register a third party ServiceProvider automatically.

**Register any Alias's**
In your Plugin.php's boot() method under any ServiceProvider lines, if you then need to add an Alias it can be done with

`$alias = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance()->alias('YourAlias', 'Third\Party\Facade');`

check this link https://github.com/Shahiem/CKeditor-plugin/blob/master/Plugin.php#L53